# In python, if extract a tar.gz file, how to get or set the name of the result file

Tags: python, tarfile, compression

My question is like: 
when use:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

if the file before compress called "sampleFolder", after I doing the above steps, how to return the "sampleFolder" name, better with its full path, or how to set the result to other name like "Folder"?

it's not a good question, but I actually have demand on this in my project.

I have to edit the question to: if I don't know the "sampleFolder", can I get a return to it after the decompress step

Comment: Use the other methods to get info about the archive.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall Just use the `path` keyword

Comment: You can use the `getmembers` method to list the files in the archive, but the archive can contain multiple files. If you want to put them all in one folder, you can create a new one and use the answer below.

Comment: ~Thanks. I'll accept the answer below if you don't mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will be extracted to the working directory by default:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

So, the path to the extracted data is:

```
from pathlib import Path
extracted_to_path = Path.cwd() / 'sampleFolder'
```

To extract in a different location:

```
with tarfile.open('sample.tar.gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall(path='/other/folder')
```

---

*edit:* If you just want to know the name `"sampleFolder"` contained in the archive, it's not necessary to extract somewhere.  You should use [`getnames`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames):

```
tar.getnames()
```

Note that tarballs can have multiple files or folders within.

Comment: you misunderstand my question, I want to get the result folder name after the decompress step

Comment: The resulting folder name after the decompress step is the `extracted_to_path`.

Comment: The asker doesn't have "sampleFolder", they are looking to find it.

Comment: I think the OP misunderstands how tarballs work, i.e. that they can contain multiple files and not just one file or directory.

Comment: I figured, set path in the extractall(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python provides **shutil** library which can extract zip files.

```
import shutil
help(shutil.unpack_archive)
```

> `unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir=None, format=None)`
> `Unpack an archive.`
>
> ```
> `filename` is the name of the archive.
>
> `extract_dir` is the name of the target directory, where the archive
> is unpacked. If not provided, the current working directory is used.
>
> `format` is the archive format: one of "zip", "tar", "gztar", "bztar",
> or "xztar".  Or any other registered format.  If not provided,
> unpack_archive will use the filename extension and see if an unpacker
> was registered for that extension.
>
> In case none is found, a ValueError is raised.
> ```

```
shutil.unpack_archive(filename="file_path", extract_dir="path_where_you_want_extracted_file", format="tar/zip")
```